# Writing a concise string storage pattern

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a series of classes used to represent identifiers in my project that are supposed to have a specific string storage format. I don't have control on this format.

The classes are pure containers, they don't do anything. The storage format is of the form "CLASSSTYPE|key1|key2|key3|...|keyN". Each "key" can be mapped to one property of the class.

Right now the FromStorageString and ToStorageString functions look like this:

```
public class SomeTypeId : IObjectId
{
    public static string ToStorageString(SomeTypeId id)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", typeof(SomeTypeId).Name, MyIntKey, MyStringKey);
    }

    public static SomeTypeId FromStorageString(IdReader source)
    {
        int intKey = source.Retrieve<int>();
        string stringKey = source.Retrieve<string>();
        return new SomeTypeId(intKey, stringKey);
    }

    public int MyIntKey { get; private set; }

    public string MyStringKey { get; private set; }

    public SomeTypeId(int intKey, string stringKey)
    {
        MyIntKey = intKey;
        MyStringKey = stringKey;
    }
}
```

We are checking the From/To consistency in unit tests, but I feel there should be a way to simplify the set up and perform the check a compile-time.

What I had in mind is something like this:

```
[Storage("MyIntKey", "MyStringKey")]
public class SomeTypeId : IObjectId
{

    private SomeTypeId() {}

    public int MyIntKey { get; private set; }

    public string MyStringKey { get; private set; }

    public SomeTypeId(int intKey, string stringKey)
    {
        MyIntKey = intKey;
        MyStringKey = stringKey;
    }

}
```

But first I don't know how to do this with the no parameters constructor and the property setters staying private. I am reluctant to have them public.

Second this approach is not robust to property name change and typos because the property names in the attribute are strings.

Should I expose the setters and private constructor ?

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: Your storage format decisions is... questionable. Why do you want to homebrew this whole thing when good, readily tested storage solutions are available? Serialization is not something your need to reinvent. Just decide for one available version.

Comment: If the code works, this questions might be better off asked on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @nvoigt: As I said I have no control on the format.

Comment: @LauLu That's why it's a comment and not an answer. You may want to ask those questions higher up the chain of command to someone who *has* control. Maybe there is a reason. Maybe there is no reason other than "I had to pick one". You will never know until you ask. Maybe someone meant to save hard disk space? Will he think the same when he knows that if you picked another format he could buy boxes full of hard disks just from the money he saved on you not implementing this less-than-optimal format?